# AngularJS $http.get not working. Not retrieving data

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter, angularjs-http

I'm new to AngularJS but I've already done a lot of things.
I did a $http.post, that worked like a charm. 
 
**Heres the Angular code**

```
$scope.login = function(user, pass) {
$scope.bIsVisible = false;

var dados = {"user": user, "pass": pass};
console.log(dados);

$http.post('http://base.corretoconcursos.com.br/cadernos/index.php/manageUsers/login', dados)
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  if (data == false) 
  {
    $scope.isLogged = false;
    $scope.bIsVisible = true;
  } else {
    $scope.isLogged = true;
    $scope.userData = data;
    console.log(data);
  }
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  alert('failed');
  $scope.bIsVisible = true;
});
```

And the **manageUsers/login** function

```
function login()
{
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $data = json_decode($postdata);

    $username = $data->user;
    $password = md5($data->pass);

    $datafrombase = $this->UsersModel->getUser(array(
        'user' => $username,
        'pass' => $password
        ));

    if ($datafrombase != null) {
        $user = array(
                    'user' => $datafrombase['user'],
                    'type' => $datafrombase['type'],
                    'logged_in' => true
                    );
        $this->session->set_userdata($user);
    }

    if ($datafrombase != null)
        print_r(json_encode($datafrombase));
    else
        return false;
}
```

Alright. It's working. I retrieve some data from database and OK. The real problem is when I do a **$http.get** and simply by doing a request on database or not, it doesn't send back the data that I want, when I do the console.log(data), it shows me an entirely HTML page, in fact, the one that is displaying. I'm getting a 200 status OK, but, a HTML page is coming. Don't know why.

Heres the **Angular code**

```
$scope.setLoggedOn = function(on) {

if (on) {

    $http.get('http://base.corretoconcursos.com.br/cadernos/index.php/manageUsers/retrieveLogin')
      .success(function(data, status) {
          console.log(data);
      })
      .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert('failed');
      });
}
else
  $scope.isLogged = false;
};
```

And heres the **PHP code function** I'm retrieving.

```
function retrieveLogin()
{
    $user = null;

    $user = array(
        'user' => $this->session->userdata('user'),
        'type' => $this->session->userdata('type'),
        'logged_in' => true
        );

    print_r(json_encode($user));
}
```

I'm stuck. I've even tried doing just a **'return true';** inside the php function, **return 'string';** but nothing will work. What so wrong am I doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. If you're using CodeIgniter along sessions; and checking in the constructor if people are logged in to let them see that page or not; when you do the $http.get it will run the constructor and run that condition, and if they cannot see that page, even if you're just doing a request from that controller via AJAX, it won't let you make the request.

I thought that the $http.get would only request the function (i-e, verifyUserInDatabase();), and give the data, but turns out, it doesn't.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

$datafrombase is never set in retrieveLogin() so angular isn't going to receive anything.

Comment: I fixed it. Sorry, my bad. But the thing is, even if I just make a $user = 1 and do print_r($user), in angular, and console.log(data) will print my whole HTML page, not the data.

Comment: You shouldn't be using print_r to output data to angular, use echo

Comment: Already tried that. That's the problem, even if I do the same thing as the another $http.post I did, like the first function that is working perfectly, it does not work. It is always retrieving a whole HTML code page.

Comment: It get the HTTP response, its not emulating a browser. make sure you are setting your content type header to application/json